# Apache Camel - File Transfer on Particular Route Call

Tags: apache, apache-camel, spring-dsl, camel-ftp

I'm trying to create a webservice which, when called look into a local directory picks up files from there and upload to the ftp server.

I'm able to create a simple route which picks file from local directory and uploads to ftp server below is the code :

```
<route>
        <from uri="file://D:\\FTPTest?noop=true&amp;delay=2000" />
        <to uri="ftp://user@host.in:21/public_html/EnterpriseProject?password=password123#"/>
        <to uri="bean:myBean?method=test" />
    </route>
```

But, I want to this file transfer to be called when a particular route is called via restlet webservice is called, I tried with the following code, but it didn't work :

```
<route>
        <from uri="direct:fileTransferRoute" />
            <to uri="file://D:\\FTPTest?noop=true&amp;delay=2000" />
            <to uri="ftp://user@host.in:21/public_html/EnterpriseProject?password=password123#"/>
        </route>
```

The above route is called by restlet from following route :

```
<route>
<from
            uri="restlet:http://0.0.0.0:9080/csitec/{serviceName}?restletMethod=post" />
        <process ref="serviceRouteProcessor" />
        <toD uri="direct:${in.header.nextRoute}" />

    </route>
```

Here's the code of my serviceRouteProcessor :

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String serviceName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Constants.SERVICE_NAME).toString();
    String nextRoute = serviceName+Constants.NEXT_ROUTE_APPENDER;
    exchange.getOut().setHeader(Constants.NEXT_ROUTE, nextRoute);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(body);
}
```

Please help me and suggest the changes needs to be done to make it work like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the pollEnrich feature of [content-enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html)

In the example section you can find a example regarding files.

Your route should look something like this(I work only with camel java dsl, so this a bit xml pseudo code):

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:fileTransferRoute" />
        <pollEnrich uri="file://D:\\FTPTest?fileName=data.txt....." />
        <to uri="ftp://user@host.in:21/public_html/EnterpriseProject?password=password123#"/>
    </route>
```

Comment: I have added your route as example to my answer.

Comment: Attribute 'uri' is not allowed to appear in element 'pollEnrich'. Its strange im getting this error. However, its working fine with :  <pollEnrich>
   <constant>file://D:\\FTPTest?noop=true&amp;delay=2000;</constant>
   </pollEnrich>

This is what i was actually looking for thanks a lot

Comment: @Siddharth the error depends on fact that up to camel 2.15 `enrich` and `pollEnrich` syntax was like the answer, from camel 2.16 the syntax changed a bit and works like your comment.

Answer (score 2):

***Edited :***

you must understand one thing first , `to` is producer not consumer  `<to uri="file://D:\\FTPTest?noop=true&amp;delay=2000" />`

What you can do is ,

```
@Autowired
private CamelContext context;// if you have more than one camel context use @Qualifier and wire by bean id


public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String serviceName = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Constants.SERVICE_NAME).toString();
    context.startRoute(serviceName+Constants.NEXT_ROUTE_APPENDER);// here in nextroute you must give the routeid
}
```

your route must look like

```
 <route id = "<value of serviceName+Constants.NEXT_ROUTE_APPENDER>" autoStartup = "false">
                <from uri="file://D:\\FTPTest..." />
                <onCompletion onFailureOnly="true">
                  <choice>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${property.CamelBatchComplete}</simple>
                    <process ref="asyncSelfShutdownProcessor"/>
                    </when>
                  </choice>
                </onCompletion>
                <to uri="ftp://user@host.in:21..."/>
            </route>
```

And add asyncSelfShutdownProcessor to spring context

```
@Component
public class AsyncSelfShutdownProcessor implements AsyncProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context

     public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback){

          new Thread(() -> context.stopRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId())).start();
     }
}
```

**##############################################################################**
***Old :***

OK I understand your need as - you have a route that moves file from file system to ftp server, all you need is this route to get executed only when you trigger from a rest service. I would do it like this ,

*I will make the route `autoStartup = "false"` and assign as `id = "fs-to-ftp"` to the route

```
<route id = "fs-to-ftp" autoStartup = "false">
            <from uri="file://D:\\FTPTest..." />
            <onCompletion onFailureOnly="true">
                <process ref="asyncSelfShutdownProcessor"/>
            </onCompletion>
            <to uri="ftp://user@host.in:21..."/>
        </route>
```

**Add a self shutdown async process in `onComplete` to the route "fs-to-ftp".  [Async Processor](https://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html)

```
asyncSelfShutdownProcessor= AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.convert(exchange -> {
            new Thread(() -> context.stopRoute("fs-to-ftp")).start();
        });
```

***Add the camel context dependency to rest service and start the route by id in the rest service `context.startRoute("fs-to-ftp")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sagar , actually I'm calling other routes from restlet with <toD .... /> so, how can I call a route with particular id in that ?

Comment: Is there any way in which I can give <from uri="direct:fileTransferRoute" /> this in my route and do the file transfer process ?

Comment: Actually if you want use `<from uri="direct:fileTransferRoute" />` then you must read and stream the files to `"direct:fileTransferRoute"` programatically and camel won't pick by itself

Comment: May be you should add your restful service code for better understanding of your scenario

Comment: I added all the related code, can help me now, please.

Comment: Now, route is not stopping here's the logs : 2016-11-24 13:38:24 INFO   [Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy:628 - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 227 seconds. Inflights per route: [fileTransfer = 2]
2016-11-24 13:38:24 DEBUG  [Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy:757 - There are 1 inflight exchanges:
 InflightExchange: [exchangeId=ID-dell-52675-1479974705034-0-7, fromRouteId=fileTransfer, routeId=fileTransfer, nodeId=to4, elaps

Comment: do you have more than one file in the folder .. in which case you should use batch consumer

Comment: Yeah, it do have more than one file, any reference to implement batch consumer would be really helpful.

Comment: just add &antInclude=* to you from  <from uri="file://D:\\FTPTest?noop=true&amp;delay=2000&amp;antInclude=*" /> and add condition in onCompletion  for property CamelBatchComplete to true

Comment: Even in case of single file its not shutting down. Showing there are 1 inflight exchanges

Comment: I'm unable to call other services now. As this one is not shutting down.

Comment: AsyncProcessor  is not a class its an interface also im getting syntax error in new thread line. please check bro.

Comment: there's some problem with this line please try in your IDE :           new Thread(() -> context.stopRoute(exchange.getFromRouteId())).start();

Comment: And boolean to return?